# bxSlider captions - Multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider for a website and I need to get the caption to use the title AND alt attributes.

The code in the bxSlider jQuery is as follows;

```
{var c = a("img", g.eq(x)).attr("title"); if (c != "") { if (b.captionsSelector) { a(b.captionsSelector).html(c) }
```

Now, I can easily change this to use one, or the other, attribute. I'm unsure ho to get this to use BOTH title and alt.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this... For anoybody looking for a similar solution in the future it's as simple as adding;

```
+ a("img", g.eq(x)).attr("atitle")
```

So this;

```
{ var c = a("img", g.eq(x)).attr("alt"); if (c != "") { if (b.captionsSelector) { a(b.captionsSelector).html(c) }
```

Becomes this;

```
{ var c = a("img", g.eq(x)).attr("alt") + a("img", g.eq(x)).attr("atitle"); if (c != "") { if (b.captionsSelector) { a(b.captionsSelector).html(c) }
```